# jQuery - add text and var to value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add normal text and a jQuery value to an input value.

```
var amount = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $('.customfield').val('clicks,<?php echo $userdata['id'] ?>,' + amount +);
```

This is what I have, but that doesn't work. Can someone explain to me, how it's done?

Comment: `$('.customfield').val('clicks,<?php echo $userdata['id'] ?>,' + amount);` - no need for the last `+`?

Comment: `$('option:selected', this).val();` is wrong. try it as  `$('option:selected').val();`

Comment: delete second parametr of jQuery selector and also last + of setting value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.customfield').val('clicks,<?php echo $userdata["id"] ?>,' + amount);

//--------double quote to id as is open and   ---------^^^^
//                   closed by single quote and remove last +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = $('option:selected').val();
    $('.customfield').val('clicks,<?php echo $userdata['id'] ?>,' + amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = $('option:selected').val(); // or var amount = $('#selectDropwdownId').val();
    $('.customfield').val("clicks,<?php echo $userdata['id'] ?>," + amount );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var amount = $('option:selected').val();
$('.customfield').val('clicks, <?php echo $userdata["id"] ?>,'+amount+');
```